# PyPi Django installation incomplete

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pip

I've encountered an interesting issue, and haven't yet managed to solve it with Google.

I'm using virtualenv+python3.5. After a number of ImportErrors, I came to a conclusion that my Django installation is incomplete.

Here's a tree of the installation:

```
(dw_dev) 15:24 ~/.virtualenvs/dw_dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django $ tree -d -L 1
.
├── __pycache__
├── apps
├── bin
├── conf
├── contrib
├── core
├── db
├── dispatch
├── forms
├── http
├── middleware
├── template
├── templatetags
├── test
├── utils
└── views
```

Modules list from Django repo:

```
apps    
bin 
conf    
contrib 
core    
db  
dispatch    
forms   
http    
middleware  
template    
templatetags    
test    
urls    
utils   
views
```

As you can see, urls module is missing. Also, exception.py is missing from middleware.

Here's what I've tried:

```
pip install django -U
pip uninstall django -y && pip install django --no-cache-dir
```

All of the above still resulted with the incomplete version.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that was dumb. I was comparing my installation with the master branch. When I chose the correct branch (1.9.x stable in my case), everything clicked in its place.